# Let Tika suggest a file-extension

Tags: java, apache-tika

I retrieve the content of a file via HTTP-request and let Tika guess which MIME type it is most likely, e.g.

```
byte[] myFileContent;
.....
String mime_type=new Tika().detect(myFileContent);
```

Then I store the content in the File system and calculate the M5-sum as unique file name (only several hundereds of files). Most likely the content is PDF.

```
String extension=".pdf";
File write=new File(MD5 + extension);
if (write.exists()) {....
  ....
}
```

Matter of fact is that I want to set the content more or less dynamically. Is there some way to retrieve the list automatically? Instead of using a handmade list for checking? Something like

```
extension=Tika.suggestFileExtension(myFileContent);
```

Comment: Wouldn't the MIME-type be in the HTTP response?

Comment: Not really - I mean it would be great but the data is encapsulated in JSON - therefore the type remains as text. But the hint is nice and I like it :-)